# Laravel Eloquent splitting query into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

Bit of a bad title, not quite sure how to research/describe what I'm trying to do.

I have a table called specifications with the fields

```
id, device_id, name, detail
```

Two rows for two different devices would for example be

```
1, 1, weight, 300kg
2, 2, weight, 250kg
```

Now the way I need to display it is in a single table compare both devices, essentially like this:

```
@foreach($specifications as $specification)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $specification->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $specification->detailOne }}</td>
        <td>{{ $specification->detailTwo }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I'm having issues getting the right query or split the query in order to be able to go through the array like above. Anyone mind putting me on the right mindset? Do I query both specs and somehow resort it into an array I can use as above, or is there something else I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
@foreach($specifications->groupBy('name') as $name => $specificationGrouped)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $name }}</td>
        @foreach($specificationGrouped as $specification)
            <td>{{ $specification['detail'] }} ({{ $specification['device_id'] }})</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks vnull, but this wouldn't work for e.g. 5 different specs for both devices. Weight is not the only value per spec (my bad)

Comment: Jamie000012 that solution works for any spec i'll post an output example and how i tested it

Comment: Thanks, when I tested it it would come out as:

Weight - 300kg 300cm
Weight - 250kg 250cm 

Should be:
Weight - 300kg 250kg
Height - 300cm 250cm

Comment: I've seen your latest edit and yes it's not what I mean as I would need it to come out as such:   
   
Weight - 250kg (computer) 350kg(fotball)   
size: 40cm (computer)

Comment: Updated check it. Sorry i understood the opposite thing first

Comment: This works perfect, I was already grouping by name in the controller but still didn't get it exactly, removed that from the query with your code in the view. Need to brush up on my basic loops obviously! Thanks.