# PHP Group by foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Having some issues visualising how to implement this for each loop and not sure where to go for clarification.

I have a database with 3 tables: items, shops, links.

Links are connected to a shop and a item, item and shop are separate tables so links have a belong to shop and belong to item relationship.

On the page which displays two specific items, the end result I'm looking for is something like this:

```
Shop      | Item 1 | Item 2 - table headings
--------- | ------ | -------
Shop-name | Link   | Link
```

To attempt to clarify a little more what I am trying to do:

```
Item[TABLE]
Item 1
Item 2

Shop[TABLE]
Shop 1
Shop 2

Links[TABLE]
Link 1 (belongs to item 1 and shop 1)
Link 2 (belongs to item 2 and shop 1)
```

Page: shows Item 1 and item 2.

Querying all Links from DB on this page, now need to group them in such a way that I get them in a single table, grouped by the shop. Does this make sense?

Any advice on how to get to this result? I am using Laravel, Eloquent and Blade.

Comment: what is your intended result ? Maybe you should write a few shop/item/links example and a example of the result your expecting, It would help us alot also.

Comment: This looks more like a db query problem rather than php

Comment: @NicolasRacine the intended result is as displayed, a table of shops that have links in them that correlate to the items on the page. Every page displays two specific items, so I need to display a table with all available links for those products. The issue I have wrapping my head around is that I  think I can't group by shop, as I am querying the links for both items first and not the shops. For context I am also showing specs for items on the same page, which I got help with here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526344/laravel-eloquent-splitting-query-into-array

Comment: I don't think grouping (at least in terms of SQL-type grouping) is what you should be trying to do to accomplish this, because it looks like your goal is really to display every link rather than the result of some aggregate function. I assume that not every shop has every item, so some of the cells in the table should be empty, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly @Don'tPanic, the reason I got to this train of thought is because of the question I linked in the comment above yours. Where someone helped me group specs together for two items that displays it in the table exactly the way I need to display it for these links. The only real difference here is that the links are connected to shops and items, and need to group them by shop, as opposed to just the specs connected to an item, and grouped by the name which is a column in the specs table. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not really asking for code, but more just a general idea of how to do this. Here is one way that should work, and probably how I would try to do it. I would execute two queries, first one to get all the items, and then one that left joins shops to links (so you get all the shops, and any links associated with each one.)

Loop over the items once to generate the column headings. Then, for each shop, loop over the items again to generate the cells in the shop row. For each item, print a link if the shop has a link for that item, or a blank cell if the shop doesn't have a link for that item. This way you will have a column for each item in each shop row, whether that shop has the item or not.

Pseudocode:

```
<tr>
foreach items
    print <th>item name</th>
</tr>

foreach shops
    <tr>
        <td>shop name</td>
        foreach items
            <td>if item has link in shop->links print link</td>
    </tr>
```

As far as how to do the eloquent queries and other specifics, it's hard to give a real PHP code example without seeing more of what you already have, but hopefully this will show at least the idea behind one way you can accomplish this.

I think that because it's theoretically possible to have a shop with no items, or an item that isn't in any shop, if you wanted to do all of this in the database you'd need something like a full outer join, which MySQL does not do as far as I know. There may be other ways to accomplish it, and if someone better at database stuff has an idea I'd be interested to see an answer like that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's immensely helpful and I will tinker around with the idea. Exact code not necessary, I just have trouble wrapping my head around more complex loops but if I have written pseudo code I can usually figure it out! I will get back to this.

Comment: Good luck! Please let me know if there's anything I need to clarify there, and I will try to improve the answer.